# Sum of a list of matrices in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, sum

I am trying to put a list of matrices together in a list and then do summation inside of each list. Below are the simple example of the codes:

Let's say if I have 4 matrices:

```
x1 <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
x2 <- matrix(2:10, nrow = 3)
x3 <- matrix(3:11, nrow = 3)
x4 <- matrix(4:12, nrow = 3)
```

And I want to put them into a `list()` in a way like this:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

[[1]][[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5    8
[2,]    3    6    9
[3,]    4    7   10


[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    6    9
[2,]    4    7   10
[3,]    5    8   11

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    7   10
[2,]    5    8   11
[3,]    6    9   12
```

And how do I perform summation of each element inside the `list()`?
For example, my desired output is as below:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    9   15
[2,]    5   11   17
[3,]    7   13   19

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    6    9
[2,]    4    7   10
[3,]    5    8   11

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    7   10
[2,]    5    8   11
[3,]    6    9   12
```

I have tried using `` list(Reduce(`+`, x)) `` however it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to keep top-level list use `lapply` :

```
lapply(x, function(l) if(is.list(l)) Reduce(`+`, l) else l)

#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    9   15
#[2,]    5   11   17
#[3,]    7   13   19

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    6    9
#[2,]    4    7   10
#[3,]    5    8   11

#[[3]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    4    7   10
#[2,]    5    8   11
#[3,]    6    9   12
```

Answer (score 1):

A corresponding `purrr` version of ***@RonakShah***'s answer with `map_if()`:

```
library(purrr)

map_if(x, is.list, reduce, `+`)

# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    9   15
# [2,]    5   11   17
# [3,]    7   13   19
# 
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    6    9
# [2,]    4    7   10
# [3,]    5    8   11
# 
# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    4    7   10
# [2,]    5    8   11
# [3,]    6    9   12
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it is more elegant to use an `array`.  Here is some example code.  The example computes the mean instead of the sum.

```
R <- list(matrices, all of the same dimension)
# Combine all these into an array with an extra dimension
# corresponding to the different matrices
dn <- dimnames(R[[1]])   # fetch row and column names
rn <- dn[[1]]; cn <- dn[[2]]
A <- array(unlist(R), dim=c(length(rn), length(cn), length(R)),
           dimnames=list(rn, cn, NULL))
# Compute mean (separately for each metrix cell) 
# over matrices, ignoring NAs
Rmean <- apply(R, 1:2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```